# botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials - Github Actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, github-actions

I am trying to run AWS SDK python script using Github Actions. Github actions is installing Boto3 successfully but script is executing with following error:

**error:**

```
Run python3 s3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s3.py", line 5, in <module>
    response = s3.list_buckets()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.6/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", 
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.6/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 162, in sign
    auth.add_auth(request)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.6/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 357, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

**Implemented so far:**

ListS3bucket.yml

```
name: Python package
on: [push]
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: sample code
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: checkout repo content
      uses: actions/checkout@v2 # checkout the repository content to github runner.
    - name: setup python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.8 
    - name: Upgrade PIP
      run: |
          /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.6/x64/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    - name: install boto3
      run: |
          python -m pip install boto3   
    - name: execute script 
      env:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: us-east-1
      run: |
          python3 s3.py
```

s3.py

```
import boto3

# Retrieve the list of existing buckets
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.list_buckets()

# Output the bucket names
print('Existing buckets:')
for bucket in response['Buckets']:
    print(f'  {bucket["Name"]}')
```

Kindly guide on this.

Comment: Can you try with env variables as: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`

Comment: yes it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution was that the env variable set were incorrect. The correct ones are `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html).